# Predefining Javascript attribute based on bootstrap field input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I currently have a text box that is a form and that data is stored in a SharePoint list.

I have the 'Client Name' stored in a SharePoint list called 'API_ClientName':

[image: form image]

How do I take that Client Name and predefine it in other fields in my SharePoint list? Something like this:

1. ACI_AccountName ------- AD **ClientName**
2. ACI_Username --------- ad**clientname**
3. ACI_FirstName -------- admin (always keep this name)
4. ACI_LastName --------- admin (always keep this name)
5. ACI_Email ---------- admin@AD.com (Always keep this email)

Code:

```js
function getItem() {
 
 var item = {
      Title: $("#ACI_client-name-input").val(), // Client Name
      ACI_Email: $("admin@AD.com").val(), // NOT SURE EMAIL IS CORRECTLY FORMATTED TO BE STATIC
      ACI_ClientName: $("      ").val(), // Account Name
    ACI_Username: $("   ").val(), // Username
    ACI_FirstName: $("   ").val(), // First Name
    ACI_LastName: $("   ").val(), // Last Name
 };
 return item;
}

function AddListItem(resources) {
 
 var item = getItem();
 
 $pnp.setup({
  baseUrl: "url..."
 });
  
 $pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("MailChimpIntake").items.add(item).then(function(r){
  $("#submit").hide();
  $("#cancel").hide();
  
  var newItem = r.data;
  
  window.location = 'url...';
 });
```

```html
<div class="form-group row" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
   <label for="ACI_client-name-input" class="col-lg-10 col-form-label">Client Name</label>
   <div class="col-lg-8">
     <input class="form-control" type="text" id="ACI_client-name-input" placeholder="" required>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Got it figured out

`Title: $("#ACI_client-name-input").val(), // Client Name

ACI_AccountName: "FH " + $("#ACI_client-name-input").val(),
ACI_Username: "fh" + $("#ACI_client-name-input").val(), // Username
ACI_FirstName: "....", // First Name
ACI_LastName: "...", // Last Name
ACI_Email: "....", // Email`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it figured out:

```js
Title: $("#ACI_client-name-input").val(), 
// Client Name ACI_AccountName: "FH " + $("#ACI_client-name-input").val(), ACI_Username: "fh" + $("#ACI_client-name-input").val(), 
// Username ACI_FirstName: "....", 
// First Name ACI_LastName: "...", 
// Last Name ACI_Email: "....", 
// Email
```